# Eventually consistent document store database similar to cassandra

Tags: database, scaling, distributed, nosql

I'm looking for an open source data store that scales as easily as Cassandra but data can be queried via documents like MongoDB.

Are there currently any databases out that do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this website [http://nosql-database.org](http://nosql-database.org/) you can find a list of many NoSQL databases sorted by datastore types, you should check the Document stores there.

I'm not naming any specific database to avoid a biased/opinion-based answer, but if you are interested in a data store that is as scalable as Cassandra, you probably want to check those which use master-master/multi-master/masterless (you name it, the idea is the same) architecture, where both writes and reads can be split among all nodes in the cluster.

I know Cassandra is optimized towards writes rather than reads, but without further details in the question can't refine the answer with more information.

Update:

> **Disclaimer**: I haven't used CouchDB at all, and haven't tested it's performance either.

Since you spotted CouchDB I'll add what I've found in the official documentation, in the [distributed database and replication](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/intro/overview.html#distributed-updates-and-replication) section.

> CouchDB is a peer-based distributed database system. It allows users
>   and servers to access and update the same shared data while
>   disconnected. Those changes can then be replicated bi-directionally
>   later.
>
> The CouchDB document storage, view and security models are designed to
>   work together to make true bi-directional replication efficient and
>   reliable. Both documents and designs can replicate, allowing full
>   database applications (including application design, logic and data)
>   to be replicated to laptops for offline use, or replicated to servers
>   in remote offices where slow or unreliable connections make sharing
>   data difficult.
>
> The replication process is incremental. At the database level,
>   replication only examines documents updated since the last
>   replication. Then for each updated document, only fields and blobs
>   that have changed are replicated across the network. If replication
>   fails at any step, due to network problems or crash for example, the
>   next replication restarts at the same document where it left off.
>
> Partial replicas can be created and maintained. Replication can be
>   filtered by a javascript function, so that only particular documents
>   or those meeting specific criteria are replicated. This can allow
>   users to take subsets of a large shared database application offline
>   for their own use, while maintaining normal interaction with the
>   application and that subset of data.

Which looks quite scalable to me, as it seems you can add new nodes to the cluster and then all the data gets replicated.

Also partial replicas seems an interesting option for really big data sets, which I'd configure these very carefully, in order to prevent situations where a given query to the database might not yield valid results, for example, in the case of a network partition and having only access to a partial set.